# text color of text field changes for some words when long pressed

Tags: ios, uitextview, textcolor, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I'm using `JSQMessagesViewController` and I noticed that it I long press an outgoing cell, if it has certain text, such as dollar amount or a date, the text color will change to black when long pressed.

Here is a before and after screenshot (I long press the first cell):

[image]

[image]

You can see the "$1,300" mysteriously turns black. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I had been reviewing the code of the library `JSQMessagesViewController` and here are my results

first you need to add in `JSQMessagesCellTextView` in the .h

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) UIColor * originalTextColor;
```

and then in the .m

add this method

```
- (BOOL)haveValidLinks
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeAddress
                                | NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber | NSTextCheckingTypeDate
                                                               error:&error];

    NSInteger number = [detector numberOfMatchesInString:self.text options:NSMatchingWithoutAnchoringBounds range:NSMakeRange(0, self.text.length)];

    if(number > 0)
        return YES;

    return NO;
}
```

and then

replace existing code on

`- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer`

with this

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{

    if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UILongPressGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        if(![self haveValidLinks])
        {
        self.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeNone;
        self.textColor = self.originalTextColor;
        }
    }
    self.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
    //  ignore double-tap to prevent copy/define/etc. menu from showing
    if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = (UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer;
        if (tap.numberOfTapsRequired == 2) {
            return NO;
        }
    }

    return YES;
}
```

and then you need to modify `- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(JSQMessagesCollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Like this

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(JSQMessagesCollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    /**
     *  Override point for customizing cells
     */
    JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell *cell = (JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell *)[super collectionView:collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    /**
     *  Configure almost *anything* on the cell
     *
     *  Text colors, label text, label colors, etc.
     *
     *
     *  DO NOT set `cell.textView.font` !
     *  Instead, you need to set `self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.messageBubbleFont` to the font you want in `viewDidLoad`
     *
     *
     *  DO NOT manipulate cell layout information!
     *  Instead, override the properties you want on `self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout` from `viewDidLoad`
     */

    JSQMessage *msg = [self.demoData.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

    if (!msg.isMediaMessage) {

        if ([msg.senderId isEqualToString:self.senderId]) {
            cell.textView.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            cell.textView.originalTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        }
        else {
            cell.textView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            cell.textView.originalTextColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }

        cell.textView.linkTextAttributes = @{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : cell.textView.textColor,
                                              NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle | NSUnderlinePatternSolid) };
    }

    return cell;
}
```

the code is here

https://github.com/rmelian2014/JSQMessagesViewController

I hope this helps you

Comment: I'm happy you found a fix but yikes, that is a lot of changes. I think I would rather just live with it for now and hope a fix is added to the library.

Comment: I am working to add this fix to the library, but if you want you can clone my fork and there is fixed

Comment: I am working to add this fix to the library, but if you want you can use my fork of this library and this issue is fixed there. regards